# Setting up vue-mathjax in simple vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I'm new to using vue so I'm going to go through the steps to get to where I'm at...

`$ vue create vue-website`

1. manually select features

- choose vue version
- babel
- router

2. choose version 3.x
3. Use history mode for router? Y
4. In dedicated config files
5. Save this as a preset for future projects? N

`$ cd vue-website`
`$ npm install vue-mathjax`

In `src/main.js` add the line `import {VueMathjax} from 'vue-mathjax'` and update the last line to be `createApp(App).use(router).use(VueMathjax).mount('#app')`

Now in `src/views/Home.vue` under the `HelloWorld` element write `<vue-mathjax :formula="formula"></vue-mathjax>`.

And in the `export default` section write

```
data() {
    return {
      formula: '$$x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}.$$'
    }
  }
```

Finally `$ npm run serve` and open up the app.

The page fails to load because js runs into error `Cannot read property '_c' of ...`

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: It's entirely possible that the plugin/module VueMathjax is using functionality that is specific to Vue2. Considering it has not been updated in 2 years, I would try a Vue app with Vue2 and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I switched to Katex, was having issues, went back to Vue 2.x and Katex now works. I'd imagine math-jax will also work but I think I'm going to stick with Katex now haha

Answer (score 0):

You forget one problem.
You must add to index.html below a line.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>
```